# Unable to load an angularjs module in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I try to make an AngularJS application entierly in CoffeeScript but when my main module is loading, I've got this error :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the    module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

My app is very simple :

Here's my index.html :

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/coffee-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/coffeescript" src="coffee/app.coffee"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

And my app (app.coffee) is just :

```
angular.module 'app', []
```

I don't understand why my 'app' module is not available because if I replace app.coffee by its compiled version (app.js), it work.

Why? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app.coffee file gets compiled after angular tries to bootstrap the page.
What you could do to make this work is to manually bootstrap the ng-app.

In your app.coffee:

```
angular.element(document).ready ->
  angular.module 'app', []
  angular.bootstrap document, ['app']
```

and get rid of the ng-app directive on the html tag.
For more info check [Angular Bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

Me for myself would not seriously consider this setup in a productive app. I'd rather compile the coffee script server side...

Comment: Thanks for this response! I've just found AngularFun project (https://github.com/CaryLandholt/AngularFun) that is a great starting point. We can find a "bootstrap.coffee inside ;)

Comment: Of course **it's just a development configuration!**

But I decided to dig in this question. What is the most easy/fast in development stage? Serve the coffeescripts and let the browser compile them or compile the coffeescripts before serving them?

Comment: I'd compile them when building the package. So you can just serve js files. Have a look at [yeoman.io](http://yeoman.io/) and [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) for a robust and rapid dev workflow.